# The linearization of the (Iff-and-only-Iff) expression

Tags: modeling, linearization, logical-constraints

I am trying to linearize the following expression without using the Big-M formulation, but I cannot convert it. I am willing to know if there exists an efficient way to do that?

$$ Iff \quad (w=1) \Longleftrightarrow (x \Longleftrightarrow y)$$

where, $x$, $y$, and $w$ are binary variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way to linearize such a constraint would be by dividing this expression into four parts and then linearizing each of which separately.

$$ Iff \quad (w=1) \rightarrow (x \rightarrow y) \quad (\text{Part-1})$$
$$ Iff \quad (w=1) \rightarrow (y \rightarrow x) \quad (\text{Part-2})$$
$$ Iff \quad (x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow (w=1) \quad (\text{Part-3})$$
$$ Iff \quad (y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow (w=1) \quad (\text{Part-4})$$

Then, the first one can be translated as:
$$ (w) \rightarrow (\lnot x \lor y)$$
$$ \lnot(w) \lor (\lnot x \lor y)$$
$$ \lnot w \lor \lnot x \lor y$$
$$ (1-w) + (1-x) + y \geq 1 \quad (\text{Part-1})$$

The second part would be the same as the one and the result is:
$$ (1-w) + (1-y) + x \geq 1 \quad (\text{Part-2})$$

The third part can be linearized as:
$$ (\lnot x \lor y) \rightarrow (w)$$
$$ \lnot (\lnot x \lor y) \lor(w)$$
$$ (x \land \lnot y) \lor (w)$$
$$ (x \lor w) \bigwedge (\lnot y \lor w)$$
$$ (x + w \geq 1) \bigwedge ((1-y) + w \geq 1) \quad (\text{Part-3})$$
$$ (y + w \geq 1) \bigwedge ((1-x) + w \geq 1) \quad (\text{Part-4})$$

Also, the third and fourth parts can already be written as:
$$ \lnot ((\lnot x \lor y) \land (\lnot y \lor x)) \lor w$$
$$ (x + y + w \geq 1) \bigwedge (w \geq x + y - 1) \quad (\text{Part-(3,4)})$$

Comment: +1 for conjunctive normal form, which in this case turns out to yield the same formulation as the big-M approach.

Comment: @RobPratt, Thanks a lot for your help and hints.

Answer (score 4):

@A.Omidi gave a nice derivation using conjunctive normal form.  In this case, the big-M approach with $M=1$ yields the same formulation:
$$w = 1 \implies x=y$$
can be enforced via
$$-(1-w) \le x-y \le 1-w,$$
and
$$w = 0 \implies x+y=1$$
can be enforced via
$$-w \le x+y-1 \le w.$$

---

An alternative approach is to introduce a binary decision variable $v$ and impose a single equality constraint $$x+y=2v+1-w.$$

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt, for your suggestion.